# Why the last child process not continue its execution before exit?

Tags: c

I am having troubles with pipe messages and child processes.
I am trying to execute processes one by one, in the end pass the children message to parent process using pipe, without the wanted result.Moreover the last process it is in a "forever" wait.From console if i press return key it print the state but withouth the messaged i used with pipe.

Here is the portion of code of the main program:

```
//MACRO
#define MESSAGE_DATA "msg1"
void *Hangar(void *arg){


 int pipefd[2];

  char msgSend[128];
  int msgLenght = strlen(MESSAGE_DATA);
  
  //pthread_mutex_lock(&m_hangar);
  printf("Hangar: Sto contattando la torre di controllo\n");
  //pthread_mutex_unlock(&m_torre);

  //creazione processi aerei(figli del processo hangar)
  for(int i=0;i<10;i++){
       sleep(2);

       printf("\tAttesa: In corso preparativi: pulizia-controllo dispoisitvi,imbarco vivande...\n");
       sleep(get_random(3,8));
    
        if(fork() == 0){ //processo figlio-aereo
            //chiusura read end della pipe in uso
            close(pipefd[0]);
            
            printf("\nArrivo dell'aereo %d,proveniente dall'hangar %d\n",getpid(),getppid());

            printf("\nInvio notifica dello stato degli aerei all'hangar di partenza\n");
            sprintf(msgSend, "msg1");
            printf("msgSend: %s",msgSend);
            write(pipefd[1],msgSend,msgLenght);
            close(pipefd[1]);
          
            exit(0);
        }
    }//processo hangar padre aspetta la terminazione dei processi figli aereo
    //chiusura write end della pipe in uso
    close(pipefd[1]);
    memset(msgSend, '\0', sizeof(msgSend));
    read(pipefd[0], msgSend, msgLenght);
    printf("Fine Esecuzione: Messaggio ricevuto -> %s\n",msgSend);
    close(pipefd[0]);
    wait(NULL);
  pthread_exit(0);
}

int main(int argc, char **argv){

pthread_t t_hangar;

pthread_create(&t_hangar,NULL,Hangar,NULL);
pthread_join(t_hangar,NULL);


return 0;
}
```

I guess,the part creating the problem is the portion on parent process in `wait(null);`, how could i manage correctly?

Comment: you create 10 child processes but have one single `read()` and one single `wait()` in the parent. So how can you expect to collect data from all children?

Comment: Mixing threads and processes (`fork()` and `exec()`) is not a good idea.  Granted, your code here is simple enough it will (probably) work OK, but in general, use either threads or processes but not both.

Comment: You launch the 10 child processes with a single pipe connecting them to the parent.  You need a loop in the parent process to reliably read the data ± waiting until you get EOF on the pipe.  You need another loop in the parent to collect all the child processes.  For testing, at least, it would be good if the children each exited with a distinct exit status (e.g. the value of `i + 1`).  The parent should print each child's PID and exit status as it collects the results.  You should also check that system calls succeeded.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, you were right, i forgot in parent process to loop, i did it and now it works perfectly, i also followed your suggestion about the exit status about the children. Previously i also forgot to implement the eventual errors, and i just realized as you said that i didn't call `pipe()`

Comment: I've just noticed that you don't actually call `pipe()` — so you don't have a pipe connecting the processes.

Answer (score 0):

Here's working code.  It prints a peculiar mixture of Italian and English, but does behave most sanely.  You omitted an implementation for `get_random()`; I've included one (not very good, but adequate for this exercise).

```c
/* SO 7464-4707 */
#include <assert.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <unistd.h>

// MACRO
#define MESSAGE_DATA "msg1"

static int get_random(int min, int max)
{
    return (rand() % (max - min + 1)) + min;
}

static void *Hangar(void *arg)
{
    assert(arg == NULL);
    int pipefd[2];

    if (pipe(pipefd) != 0)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "pipe() failed\n");
        return 0;
    }

    char msgSend[128];

    printf("Hangar: Sto contattando la torre di controllo\n");
    fflush(stdout);

    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        sleep(1);

        printf("%5d: Attesa: In corso preparativi: pulizia-controllo dispoisitvi,imbarco vivande...\n", getpid());
        fflush(stdout);

        int pid = fork();
        if (pid == 0)
        {
            srand(getpid());
            int nap = get_random(3, 8);
            sleep(nap);
            close(pipefd[0]);
            printf("\nArrivo dell'aereo %d,proveniente dall'hangar %d\n", getpid(), getppid());
            printf("\nInvio notifica dello stato degli aerei all'hangar di partenza\n");
            sprintf(msgSend, "%d: %s (%d)", getpid(), MESSAGE_DATA, nap);
            printf("msgSend: %s\n", msgSend);
            write(pipefd[1], msgSend, strlen(msgSend));
            close(pipefd[1]);
            exit(i + 1);
        }
        else
            printf("Launched %d\n", pid);
        fflush(stdout);
    }

    close(pipefd[1]);
    int nbytes;
    while ((nbytes = read(pipefd[0], msgSend, sizeof(msgSend))) > 0)
        printf("Fine Esecuzione: Messaggio ricevuto -> %.*s\n", nbytes, msgSend);
    close(pipefd[0]);

    int corpse;
    int status;
    while ((corpse = wait(&status)) > 0)
        printf("PID %d exited with 0x%.4X\n", corpse, status);
    pthread_exit(0);
}

int main(void)
{
    pthread_t t_hangar;

    pthread_create(&t_hangar, NULL, Hangar, NULL);
    pthread_join(t_hangar, NULL);

    return 0;
}
```

Sample output:

```
Hangar: Sto contattando la torre di controllo
63737: Attesa: In corso preparativi: pulizia-controllo dispoisitvi,imbarco vivande...
Launched 63740
63737: Attesa: In corso preparativi: pulizia-controllo dispoisitvi,imbarco vivande...
Launched 63742
63737: Attesa: In corso preparativi: pulizia-controllo dispoisitvi,imbarco vivande...
Launched 63743
63737: Attesa: In corso preparativi: pulizia-controllo dispoisitvi,imbarco vivande...
Launched 63744
63737: Attesa: In corso preparativi: pulizia-controllo dispoisitvi,imbarco vivande...
Launched 63745

Arrivo dell'aereo 63740,proveniente dall'hangar 63737

Invio notifica dello stato degli aerei all'hangar di partenza
msgSend: 63740: msg1 (5)
63737: Attesa: In corso preparativi: pulizia-controllo dispoisitvi,imbarco vivande...
Launched 63746

Arrivo dell'aereo 63744,proveniente dall'hangar 63737

Invio notifica dello stato degli aerei all'hangar di partenza
msgSend: 63744: msg1 (3)
63737: Attesa: In corso preparativi: pulizia-controllo dispoisitvi,imbarco vivande...
Launched 63747
63737: Attesa: In corso preparativi: pulizia-controllo dispoisitvi,imbarco vivande...
Launched 63748

Arrivo dell'aereo 63742,proveniente dall'hangar 63737

Invio notifica dello stato degli aerei all'hangar di partenza
msgSend: 63742: msg1 (7)

Arrivo dell'aereo 63745,proveniente dall'hangar 63737

Invio notifica dello stato degli aerei all'hangar di partenza
msgSend: 63745: msg1 (4)
63737: Attesa: In corso preparativi: pulizia-controllo dispoisitvi,imbarco vivande...
Launched 63749
63737: Attesa: In corso preparativi: pulizia-controllo dispoisitvi,imbarco vivande...
Launched 63750
Fine Esecuzione: Messaggio ricevuto -> 63740: msg1 (5)63744: msg1 (3)63742: msg1 (7)63745: msg1 (4)

Arrivo dell'aereo 63743,proveniente dall'hangar 63737

Invio notifica dello stato degli aerei all'hangar di partenza
msgSend: 63743: msg1 (8)
Fine Esecuzione: Messaggio ricevuto -> 63743: msg1 (8)

Arrivo dell'aereo 63746,proveniente dall'hangar 63737

Invio notifica dello stato degli aerei all'hangar di partenza
msgSend: 63746: msg1 (5)
Fine Esecuzione: Messaggio ricevuto -> 63746: msg1 (5)

Arrivo dell'aereo 63747,proveniente dall'hangar 63737

Invio notifica dello stato degli aerei all'hangar di partenza
msgSend: 63747: msg1 (6)
Fine Esecuzione: Messaggio ricevuto -> 63747: msg1 (6)

Arrivo dell'aereo 63750,proveniente dall'hangar 63737

Invio notifica dello stato degli aerei all'hangar di partenza
msgSend: 63750: msg1 (3)
Fine Esecuzione: Messaggio ricevuto -> 63750: msg1 (3)

Arrivo dell'aereo 63748,proveniente dall'hangar 63737

Invio notifica dello stato degli aerei all'hangar di partenza
msgSend: 63748: msg1 (7)
Fine Esecuzione: Messaggio ricevuto -> 63748: msg1 (7)

Arrivo dell'aereo 63749,proveniente dall'hangar 63737

Invio notifica dello stato degli aerei all'hangar di partenza
msgSend: 63749: msg1 (8)
Fine Esecuzione: Messaggio ricevuto -> 63749: msg1 (8)
PID 63750 exited with 0x0A00
PID 63748 exited with 0x0800
PID 63747 exited with 0x0700
PID 63746 exited with 0x0600
PID 63745 exited with 0x0500
PID 63744 exited with 0x0400
PID 63743 exited with 0x0300
PID 63742 exited with 0x0200
PID 63740 exited with 0x0100
PID 63749 exited with 0x0900
```

I've moved the `sleep()` calls around — the big one is in each child, and there's only a short one for the parent; I created a pipe; I've got a loop reading from the pipe; I've got a loop waiting and reporting on the children; the messages are varied (a little) per child; the length that's read is used in the writing the message that's read (it isn't a string that's sent over the pipe).